# storing different value from different client while taking feedback

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a feedback page that have textboxs, radio button, and checkboxes. 
 so how can i store the more than 40 field that have different type.
whether i have to create 40 field in database to store 40 data?
or any other way is there to store them??
or if you have any other suggestion please

Comment: those are mandatory field you have to create columns. the fields having more than one value create another transaction table having client as foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of same requirement before. I created a DB table with below columns:

1. FieldType (RadioButton,CheckBox,DropDown)
2. DataType (bool,int,string,multi)
3. Response (actual response). For multi selected I would save as comma separated string.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

serialize the entire form and use AJAX to send it to the server and store the serialized string.

### Example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

Serialize a form with `$("form").serialize()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form1").submit(function () {
        var jqxhr = $.post('api/updates/complex', $('#form1').serialize())
            .success(function () {
                var loc = jqxhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
                var a = $('<a/>', { href: loc, text: loc });
                $('#message').html(a);
            })
            .error(function () {
                $('#message').html("Error posting the update.");
            });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```